# Best way to structure fetching data that has duplicates without spamming an API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, rest

This is a methodological question about the best way to structure fetching and displaying a list of data with duplicates.

On a browse/display page - it calls an API which returns 25 items at a time - the item structure looks like this:

```
{
title: "some text", //can be duplicates
id: always_unique_value, //never duplicates
subtitle: "some text" //can be duplicates
}
```

The issue is that there can be thousands of duplicate titles. Something like:

```
{
id: 1,
title: "the same"
}
{
id: 2,
title: "the same"
}
{
id: 3,
title: "the same"
}
```

Since we can only fetch 25 items at a time - I want to group duplicates together when displaying them, but herein lies the problem.

When we group 10 items that are duplicates, the page will only have 15 unique items being displayed. So we need to fetch more items from the API. **But if there are 100 duplicates next in the API, we would have to repeatedly call the API 5 times, to get the remaining 10 unique items.**

Meaning you can run into a situation where to display 25 items, you might be calling the API 100s of times over and over, to fetch a unique set of 25 items.

So my question is - without changing the API database, how can we design this system so that its displaying 25 items on the page, without having to call this API potentially hundreds of times to get those unique items?

The API can be called with the following params:

**from** - where to start, so 0 starts at the beginning, and 25 would be page 2.

**search values** - can search for values but this won't help in displaying items

**size** - can request 100, 2000 items from the API - but we only need to display 25 per page.

I don't want to repeatedly call the API as it could be stressed and potentially enter a warning/failed state when multiple people are querying it 100 times every second

Comment: Sounds like the API is essentially nearly broken. I'd take it up with them first.

Comment: The API is used to store the data not necessarily be displayed. There are thousands of items on it, and very few are duplicates. The duplicates are not broken/invalid, they are completely valid, but for display purposes it looks nice to have 25 unique items than 25 exactly the same items being displayed

Comment: You need a fix on the API backend to allow it to batch duplicates and not count those towards the page size.  But the one thing you *can* do for now, if you are concerned with issuing too many requests, is just to overfetch the items you need.  Need 25?  Request 100 (or 500), and batch duplicates.  That will cut down on the number of requests and roundtrips.

Comment: Considering this as the only true option.... just concerned on loading times - unsure if its even a factor but wanted to see if there was any out of the box solutions that might be better before implementing